# Show that if $\partial(\Omega) \neq \emptyset$ then $\partial(\Omega)$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove that if $\partial(\Omega) \neq \emptyset$ then $\partial(\Omega)$ is closed, so we can prove that $\partial(\Omega) ^c$ is open, this means $int(\partial(\Omega)^c )=(\partial(\Omega))^c$

The first contention is clearly, but if we take $p \in (\partial(\Omega) )^c$ then $$p \notin \partial(\Omega)$$

So $\exists C_{n}\ni p$ s.t. $C_{n} \cap \Omega = \emptyset$ and $C_{n} \cap \Omega^c= \emptyset$

Remark:$C_{n}=I_{1} \times \cdots \times I_{n}$, from where $I_{i}$ is a open set of $\mathbb{R}$

But, what is the next step? any suggestion for solve this problem? i will apreciate it.

One thing:

$\partial(\Omega)$ Contains all the points $p \in \Omega$ s.t. for all $C_{n} \ni p$:

$$C_{n} \cap \Omega \neq \emptyset \quad \text{and} \quad C_{n} \cap \Omega ^c$$

$\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: What is your definition of $\partial\Omega$? (And what is $\Omega$, while you’re at it?) Edit your question to clarify these issues.

Comment: @TedShifrin Ready, corrected

Comment: $p \notin \partial \Omega$ means that there exists $C_n \ni p$ such that $C_n \cap \Omega = \varnothing$ **or** $C_n \cap \Omega^c = \varnothing$. Now proceed in each of this two cases.

Comment: @azif00 I understand, I should use my hypothesis that the boundary is different from empty? it is not clear yet

Comment: As you've defined it, $\delta(\Omega)$ is always a subset of $\Omega$.  If so, then you would always have $C_n \cap \Omega \neq \emptyset$.  Did you instead mean "$\delta(\Omega)$ contains all the points $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$ s.t. [...]" (if not, then the conclusion may be false)